# SubtleCrypto.wrapKey usage: can exportKey but not wrapKey?

Tags: rsa

I'm trying to wrap an RSA private key using an AES-256 key-wrapping key, using the SubtleCrypto API.  I've managed to make the RSA keys and key-wrapping AES key (plus another symmetric AES key) using `generateKey`, but `wrapKey` fails on the RSA private key.

I can successfully `export` and then `import` the RSA private key, and I can successfully `wrap` and `unwrap` a general-purpose AES key.  But I get a "data provide to an operation does not meet requirements" error when trying to wrap the RSA private key, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

HTML file for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test WebCrypto.subtle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test WebCrypto.subtle Functions</h1>
    <div id="output">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function TestCrypto( ) {
       $('#output').append( 'Starting test...<br/>' );
       let info = {};

       window.test_result = info;

       let seq = crypto.subtle.generateKey( { name: 'RSA-OAEP',
                                              modulusLength: 1024,
                                              publicExponent: new Uint8Array( [ 1, 0, 1 ] ),
                                              hash: 'SHA-256' },
                                            true,   // extractable
                                            [ 'encrypt', 'decrypt' ] )
                       .then( (rsaKey) =>
                         {
                           $('#output').append( 'Created RSA key<br/>' );
                           info.RSA = rsaKey;
                           return crypto.subtle.generateKey( { name: 'AES-GCM',
                                                               length: 256 },
                                                             true,
                                                             [ 'encrypt', 'decrypt' ] )
                         } )
                       .then( (symKey) =>
                         {
                           $('#output').append( 'Created symmetric AES key<br/>' );
                           info.AES = symKey;
                           return crypto.subtle.generateKey( { name: 'AES-KW',
                                                               length: 256 },
                                                             true,
                                                             [ 'wrapKey', 'unwrapKey' ] )
                         } )
                       .then( (kek) =>
                         {
                           $('#output').append( 'Created key-encryption AES key<br/>' );
                           info.KEK = kek;
                           return crypto.subtle.exportKey( 'pkcs8',
                                                           info.RSA.privateKey );
                         } )
                       .then( (expPrivKey) =>
                         {
                           $('#output').append( 'Exported RSA private key<br/>' );
                           info.exportedPrivateKey = expPrivKey;
                           return crypto.subtle.importKey( 'pkcs8',
                                                           info.exportedPrivateKey,
                                                           { name: 'RSA-OAEP',
                                                             hash: 'SHA-256' },
                                                           true,
                                                           [ 'decrypt', 'unwrapKey' ] );
                         } )
                       .then( (impPrivKey) =>
                         {
                           $('#output').append( 'Imported RSA private key<br/>' );
                           info.importedPrivateKey = impPrivKey;
                           /* Wrapping & unwrapping an AES key works...
                           return crypto.subtle.wrapKey( 'raw',
                                                         info.AES,
                                                         info.KEK,
                                                         'AES-KW' );
                            */
                           /* Wrapping & unwrapping an RSA key doesn't work... */
                           return crypto.subtle.wrapKey( 'pkcs8',
                                                         info.RSA.privateKey,
                                                         info.KEK,
                                                         'AES-KW' );
                         } )
                       .then( (wrappedKey) =>
                         {
                           $('#output').append( 'Wrapped a key<br/>' );
                           info.wrappedKey = wrappedKey;
                           /*
                           return crypto.subtle.unwrapKey( 'raw',
                                                           info.wrappedKey,
                                                           info.KEK,
                                                           'AES-KW',
                                                           { name: 'AES-GCM',
                                                             length: 256 },
                                                           true,
                                                           [ 'encrypt', 'decrypt' ] );
                           */
                           return crypto.subtle.unwrapKey( 'pkcs8',
                                                           info.wrappedPrivateKey,
                                                           info.KEK,
                                                           'AES-KW',
                                                           { name: 'RSA-OAEP',
                                                             // These items shouldn't be needed, but don't help
                                                             // even if you add them.
                                                             // modulusLength: 1024,
                                                             // publicExponent: new Uint8Array( [ 1, 0, 1 ] ),
                                                             hash: 'SHA-256' },
                                                           true,
                                                           [ 'decrypt', 'unwrapKey' ] );
                         } )
                       .then( (unwrappedKey) =>
                         {
                           $('#output').append( 'Unwrapped the key<br/>' );
                           info.unwrappedKey = unwrappedKey;
                           $('#output').append( 'Testing complete, check console for results<br/>' );
                           console.log( info );
                           window.test_result = info;
                           return info;
                         } )
                       .catch( (e) =>
                         {
                           $('#output').append( 'Key testing failed<br/>' )
                                       .append( e.toString( ) )
                                       .append( '<br/>' );
                         } );
     }

     $(document).ready( TestCrypto );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm, following the examples at Mozilla.org, they show encrypting an RSA private key using AES-GCM instead of AES-KW.  This seems to work for me, too.  So I guess the remaining question is, "is there some reason why I can't wrap an RSA private key with AES-KW?  It's supposed to handle any data longer than 64 bytes...

Comment: If this is the spec of AES-KW then it seems specifically created to target symmetric keys. The input needs to be a multiple of 64 bits too. Note that the wrapping of keys that are not fully random *after encoding* may require specific algorithms. The use of ECB and CBC is almost certain to leak informatin.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing and re-reading docs, I found the section that solves this problem:

> One advantage of using AES-KW over another AES mode such as AES-GCM is
>   that AES-KW does not require an initialization vector. **To use
>   AES-KW, the input must be a *multiple of 64 bits*.**